# Baking textures in blender after switching versions seems to cause displaced UVs

Tags: uv, texture-baking, uv-image-editor

Okay so I am not sure what infos to give here as I barely understand the problem myself now after days of trying around stuff.

What happened:
I am making models for a game in unreal engine right now, made then in blender, textured them using simple shader nodes, then UV-unwrapped more or less clean, baked the textures, mostly diffuse, roughness and normal, exported this into unreal engine, no problems whatsoever.
I did all that in 3.3, then updated to 3.4, and now something is off.

[image]

This here now is in 3.4. As you can see, for this normal chair, I used a fairly simple shader for the texture. I unwrapped it, and then baked the normal texture, and the result is visible on the left.
Normally, this would have been it, texture done, export to UE5 and next one.
But now in this blender version, when I plug in the normal texture, this happens

[image]

I experimented a bit, and although it seems lie the UVs are perfectly ontop of the baked texture areas, it seems like the texture is projected onto the model in some streched or displaced way. I have no other idea on how to word this out, I also never ran into this problem and so far 5 different people I asked had no clue.
Might be some setting I changed some time ago in 3.3, but if thats the case then I surely dont know where.
Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: Maybe the UVs are not correct?

Comment: Upload any part of ur mesh or full mesh here, upto you, but both with the material u are baking from and the baked texture, often the error u are describing is on the baking texture side, check for distorition is UVs, scale and many things, otherwise if you want a better help, kindly upload the file or part of it, to troubleshoot it

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1btbd73ZTFe4U5PDXnVIwl4bkH07Bpj0v?usp=sharing uploaded the files here, the baked normal image and the basic model of the chair with the UVs I used

Comment: Okay nevermind its a bug, I had tried to reimport the model as fbx but not obj, and reimporting the model fixed the problem, thanks for your help still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reimporting the mesh through obj file format fixed the issue